# How do I batch rewrite an SVN log?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I need to do a search/replace over the names of users making changes to my SVN repository; we're making some organizational changes so I need to change 'fantasticMan' as the author of various changes in the log to 'authorA' (just an example).

My idea was to `svn dump` and then do a search/replace over the dump file. The problem is that after the first checkout, it only gets to revision 1; when I was doing an `svnadmin load` command I got this message: `svnadmin: Dumpstream data appears to be malformed`. I suspect that there are some checksums in the log to ensure the integrity of the dumpfile so I can't just do a search and replace over the dumpfile.

How do I make changes on the author names of a repository? (If there's a way to do this without having to dump the repository and then reload the dump, I'd prefer that solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is there a way to change a SVN users username through the entire repository history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195339/is-there-a-way-to-change-a-svn-users-username-through-the-entire-repository-histo)

Using `svndumptool` works best. A.H.'s way would take me much longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svnadmin setrevprop` for that. In Linux speak:

```
svnadmin setrevprop -r1 MyRepoDir svn:author <(echo -n NewAuthor)
```

So the next question will be: How the get the old author:

```
svnlook author -r1 MyRepoDir
```

So you will basically iterate from revision 1 up to "youngest" and map each author on the way. I hope for you, that you don't have as many revisions as some Apache repositories. :-)