# Can I migrate an existing Subversion/Jenkins environment to Cloudbees?

Tags: svn, jenkins, cloudbees

We have an existing self-hosted Subversion repository and Jenkins server that we are considering moving onto CloudBees.

- Is it possible to migrate the Subversion repository maintaining all of the history **and user names**? Any advice on how to do this smoothly is appreciated.
- Is it possible to migrate our existing Jenkins job configurations and history? If so, tips appeciated.
- How well does the beta [customer provided executors](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Customer+Provided%20Slaves) feature work, as we would need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion migration is covered here:

http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Subversion+-+Importing+a+repository

There is an article covering changing authors here - 
[Is there a way to change a SVN users username through the entire repository history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195339/is-there-a-way-to-change-a-svn-users-username-through-the-entire-repository-hist)

Also - if you are subscribing to the CloudBees Pro (or higher) tier then we can load a clean dump file for you and save a lot of time in the process.

Answer (score 0):

- subversion migration is possible, even I don't remember the exact technical process, we (cloudbees) did it for some customers
- migrating job config and history is possible as well. Simplest way is for you to zip your "jobs" directory and send it
- customer provided slaves have been in beta for 3 month now and used by a significant set of beta-testers. I'm not sure when it will be considered GA, but I'm very confident on this feature.

Comment: I'm writing a FAQ about this which will go in the CloudBees wiki. Will post back once done.

Comment: Two points that I am particularly interested in are allowing our users to continue using the same user names (which are common first names) in SVN and the migration of Jenkins jobs **with history and previously published artifacts**.